# Setting up webpack for multiple paged HTML5 website

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

This is my first time working with webpack. I have read the docs articles, answers etc but that got me really confused of how to setup webpack for use with static **multiple HTML5 webpages**.

I basically want to achieve the following:

- Bundle and minify all **js** for a particular page together.
- **Convert** ES6 to ES5 using babel loader.
- Bundle and minify all **css** for a particular page together.
- **autoprefix** css properties.
- Bundle all **assets** for a particular page together.

I read about `html-webpack-plugin` but really confused on how to set it up or is there any other way.

Any examples from existing projects are also appreciated. Really would love some help. :(

## **What I have done till now:**

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "me",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "Ayan Dey",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.min.css");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./app.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.min.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader?presets[]=es2015",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: extractCSS.extract([
                    "css-loader",
                    "postcss-loader"
                ])
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|gif|jpg|png|eot|woff|ttf)$/,
                loaders: [
                    "url-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS
    ]
};
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require("autoprefixer")
    ]
};
```

Comment: Lots of seed projects around you can use as starter that do all the things you ask for

Comment: As I mentioned, am too confused with all of them as all of them have certain different approaches. I basically did the above my reading some medium articles.

Comment: Right but a seed project will get you started with samples that work out of the box

Comment: Ok, can you provide me with some links to them?

Comment: What do you mean by saying `static multiple HTML5 webpages`? SPA?

Comment: @MatheusSilva Not SPA. Just normal websites with multiple pages.

Comment: Answer your question is pretty hard, depends on how much you know about Webpack. Try to watch some tutorial on youtube, they cover pretty much all the points you listed. If you find Webpack too difficult try https://parceljs.org/ it's a lot simpler (but less powerful), there are tutorial on youtube also for Parcel

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following **webpack.config.js** solves my requirements. Though it took me quiet a while to go through many tutorials and articles but for now it works.

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name].styles.min.css");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const entryPoints = require("./app");

module.exports = {
    entry: entryPoints,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/dist"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.min.js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: ["es2015"]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: extractCSS.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            options: {
                                url: false,
                                minimize: true,
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        },
                        "postcss-loader"
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ["html-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|gif|jpg|png)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            outputPath: "assets/images/",
                            publicPath: "assets/images/"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "index.html",
            template: "src/index.html",
            chunks: ["index"]
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "page2.html",
            template: "src/page2.html",
            chunks: ["page2"]
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"])
    ]
};
```